# Can't run an exe app on linux with wine

Tags: wine, mono

I installed wine.
But when i try to run the exe app.
I get the following output.
009:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed
I then installed wine mono but i get the same output again, any fixes?

Comment: This post is **almost** off topic. If you use Kali you should not need to ask this kind of simplistic question - Kali is not a general purpose Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

wine mono (package) only downloads it to your system. You have to install it in your wine prefix with winetricks.

Your application may require .Net, which can also be installed via winetricks.